# get-aduser certificates strange error

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get AD users list with 'certificates' property. But when i'm doing

```
$users = Get-ADUser -searchbase "CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -filter * -Properties “Certificates”
```

I'm getting strange error

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot find the requested object.
At line:1 char:10
+ $users = Get-ADUser -searchbase "CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -filte ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], CryptographicException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException,Microsoft.Ac 
   tiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

When I'm doing this without variable

```
Get-ADUser -searchbase "CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -filter * -Properties “Certificates”
```

I'm getting the list of users and certificates and the error above in the end of the list.
But how can I pass data to variable? Tryed with erroraction, still no result.

Comment: This works perfectly fine for myself, I get no error when running as $users in this situation, what version are you running? i'm running 4.0 on my DC

Comment: 4.0 on DC, and 5.1 on my test vm. Tested it with 4.0 on both sides and got the same error. Weird thing. Only expandproperty works atm. I thought it's about version difference, but no. Anyway, the working method still exists and it's fine to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just threw users' samaccountnames into foreach.

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com" | select -ExpandProperty samaccountname

foreach ($u in $users) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting the list of users and certificates and the error above in
>   the end of the list. But how can I pass data to variable?

This is a question near and dear to my heart.

I've cooked up a function (f) to recreate this problem:

```
function f { write-output $(1..100); throw 'bs' }
```

If you run `f`, you'll get numbers 1 through 100 then an exception. You have a similar situation; output then a bomb.

I've never found a good way to handle this. This is what I do:

```
f 1> stuff.txt; $o = cat .\stuff.txt; rm stuff.txt -force
```

The numbers should goto stdout and exception to stderr. Or, so I think. :-)

I send the output (the numbers 1 through 100) to a file, read the file into a variable, and then delete the file. This gives you the output as a variable, but it's way hacky and gross.

Hoping someone posts something a better, but this should help you if you're in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use a Where-Object to the command like so:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -Properties * | 
    Where-Object { $null -ne $_.Certificates } | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        # write out whatever properties you need for each user
    }
```

Comment: No result. I think it's time to upgrade our DCs to PS 5.1